# SSIS Data Conversion to US ASCII

Tags: ssis

I am trying add a data conversion task in a SSIS package and details of which are below. 
[image]

I am getting below error -

```
conversion from "DT_STR" with code page 1252 to "DT_STR" with code page 21027 is not supported.
```

My input table has columns of `CHAR` attributes. How can I resolve the issue? I read somewhere that changing column properties from `VARCHAR` to `CHAR` should resolve the issue but it is still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you error message, you are trying to convert some column to codepage 21027, which is not supported on Windows since .Net 2.0. Check your data conversion transformation settings.